# Map values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, array-map

I have an array

```
const nodes = [
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'input' },
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'output' },
    { layer: '1' }
};
```

I want to keep the array, but all the layer values should be changed.

The input layer should have value 1, all the numeric values should be increased by 2 and the output layer should have the new highest numeric value plus 1. All the values should be numbers instead of strings.

So the new array will be

```
const nodes = [
    { layer: 2 },
    { layer: 1 },
    { layer: 2 },
    { layer: 4 },
    { layer: 3 }
};
```

I have accomplished this with

```
const nodes = [
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'input' },
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'output' },
    { layer: '1' }
};

const output = Math.max.apply(Math, nodes.map((node) => Number.parseInt(node.layer, 10) || 0)) + 3;

nodes.map((node) => {
  layer: neuron.layer === 'input' ? 1 : (neuron.layer === 'output' ? output : Number.parseInt(neuron.layer, 10) + 2)
})
```

It seems to work, but the code is really ugly.

I wonder if it can be done more neat than this.

Comment: This seems to fly in the face of what "constant" means.

Comment: There's at least 3 syntactical issues with your code that would not make it run at all, so I don't think you've accomplished what you think you have.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - While I tend to agree, Javascript `const`'s have never meant to be immutable.

Comment: I agree, the idea of constants in JavaScript is somewhat silly. On the topic of the original question, it's not clear of what the true goal or context is. For example, one solution that *might* be useful is to just grab a reference to the input and output objects (as they're populated?) and deal with them separately. Does it matter if these things stay the original objects? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```js
const nodes = [
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'input' },
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'output' },
    { layer: '1' }
];

nodes.filter( o => o.layer === 'output' )[0].layer = 
    1 + nodes.reduce( (max, node) => Math.max(max, 
        node.layer = +(node.layer === 'input') || +node.layer+2 || 0), 0);

console.log(nodes);
```

For those wondering about `const` here: the constant nature only protects the variable from a reassignment; but the objects stored within the array can be freely mutated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be one way of doing this job;

```js
var nodes = [
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'input' },
    { layer: '0' },
    { layer: 'output' },
    { layer: '1' }
],
result = nodes.map(n => isNaN(+n.layer) ? n.layer === "input" ? {layer:1}
                                                              : {layer: n.layer}
                                        : n.layer = {layer:+n.layer + 2});
result.find(o => o.layer === "output").layer = result.filter(f => !isNaN(f.layer))
                                                     .reduce((p,c) => p.layer > c.layer ? p : c)
                                                     .layer + 1;
console.log(result);
```